# Recurrence Relation and Explicit Formula

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms

I am looking to find the recurrence relation and explicit formula for this code:

while ($x > 0$) {
$x = x/2$;
}

Where the $x/2$ is the floor of the function.

I know from my basic computer science knowledge that this is logarithmic, but I am having a hard time proving this/finding this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to find the time complexity?